# php find week number from specific date

Tags: php, date

I want to find a specific week number from the specific start date. For example $date is dragged from the database (i.e. 07/08/2011)

I want this to be the start date so it would be week 3 now from this date. This is the code i have so far but just shows the ISO version:

```
    $date = strtotime("".$row['start_date'].""); 
$weekNumber = date("W", $date); 
print $weekNumber;
```

I have googled for past two hours but cannot seem to find any thing that resolves this! any help would be great thanks!

Comment: are you saying you want to know how many weeks are between two given dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the difference between now and the startdate, and then divide by seven days (7*86400 seconds)

```
<?php
    $startdate = strtotime("".$row['start_date'].""); 
    $enddate = time();

    $time_passed = $enddate - $startdate;

    // if the first day after startdate is in "Week 1" according to your count
    $weekcount_1 = ceil ( $time_passed / (86400*7));

    // if the first day after startdate is in "Week 0" according to your count
    $weekcount_0 = floor ( $time_passed / (86400*7));

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can drag week number from db directly along with main date.
For example,

```
"SELECT start_date, (WEEK(NOW()) - WEEK(start_date)) as desired_week as week from table";
```

Comment: That is the calendar week of the day, but not the "count of weeks since startdate"

Comment: I think you say about WEEKDAY because week returns year week number. Edited my query.