# Get Week Numbers between two dates in php

Tags: php

I want to get the week numbers for given two dates i.e from 2012-01-01 to 2012-12-31.The week numbers should fall exactly in the range as specified above.Can u please give suggestions for doing this.

Comment: Week numbers? Do you mean the number of weeks between the two dates? Or an array of the week numbers that occurred between the two?

Comment: The number of weeks between 2012-01-01 and 2012-12-31 is 52.

Comment: array of week numbers occurred between.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7223996/1276124. First you need to make an array of the first calendar day, Sun/Mon. Then loop those days through that

Comment: Thanks for giving reply.But here week 52 is duplicating

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work fine:

```
<?php
    $startDateUnix = strtotime('2012-01-01');
    $endDateUnix = strtotime('2013-01-01');

    $currentDateUnix = $startDateUnix;

    $weekNumbers = array();
    while ($currentDateUnix < $endDateUnix) {
        $weekNumbers[] = date('W', $currentDateUnix);
        $currentDateUnix = strtotime('+1 week', $currentDateUnix);
    }

    print_r($weekNumbers);
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/td2r8v07).

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 52
    [1] => 01
    [2] => 02
    .........
    [51] => 51
    [52] => 52
)
```

Comment: Thanks for giving reply...i am trying for 2012-12-01 -2013-06-30.But it giving wrong result.

Comment: @user2286462 What does it give you and what do you expect?

Comment: Can u please try with 2011-01-01 - 2011-12-31 and check

Comment: @user2286462 I can't try with the two dates, as I still don't know **what** you want to receive. Why is the result wrong? What are you expecting?

Comment: Actually i have date filters like current month,previous month,specified month,current year,previous year,specified year,this quarter,previous quarter...when i check any of these i am generating two dates between range..when i check i want display week numbers of the range what selected either month,year or quarter.

Comment: Did you understood requiremnent

Comment: @user2286462 Yes, but **why** does this return a wrong array? This returns the weeks 52 all through to 52, as 2012-01-01 is week 52, and 2013-01-01 is week 52. With these dates, what array were you expecting (from X to Y).

Comment: Week52  Tuesday  2012-12-25  2012-12-31             Week01  Tuesday  2012-1-3  2012-1-9
Week02  Tuesday  2012-1-10  2012-1-16
Week03  Tuesday  2012-1-17  2012-1-23
Week04  Tuesday  2012-1-24  2012-1-30
Week05  Tuesday  2012-1-31  2012-2-6
Week10  Tuesday  2012-3-6  2012-3-12
Week11  Tuesday  2012-3-13  2012-3-19
Week12  Tuesday  2012-3-20  2012-3-26
Week13  Tuesday  2012-3-27  2012-4-2
Week51  Tuesday  2012-12-18  2012-12-2
Week52  Tuesday  2012-12-25  2012-12-31

Comment: here week 52 came twice one is first and another is at last...both are same...i want to remove that

Comment: Excellent, I suggest change $weekNumbers[]  to $weekNumbers[date("Y-m-d",$currentDateUnix)].

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the job:

```
$start = '2012-01-01';
$end = '2012-12-31';

$dates = range(strtotime($start), strtotime($end),604800);
$weeks = array_map(function($v){return date('W', $v);}, $dates); // Requires PHP 5.3+

print_r($weeks);
```

Comment: `$start = '2012-12-15'; $end = '2013-03-21';` would output a range between `50` and `12` which is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this using DateTime:

```php
$first_date = new DateTime();
$last_date  = new DateTime('-50 weeks');
$days_array = array();
foreach(new DatePeriod($first_date, new DateInterval('P1D'), $last_date) as $date) {
  $days_array[] = $date->format('W');
}
```

Comment: Date management is full traps. I also highly recommend to use Datetime witch allow you to define the timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

[REMOVED]

EDIT

```
<?php

for($w = strtotime($start_date); $w <= strtotime($end_date); $w += 7 * 24 * 3600)
{
echo date("W", $w) . '<br />';
}

?>
```

Comment: What if $start_date was '2012-12-20' and $end_date was '2013-03-04'? That'd be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of weeks between two dates using the weeks_between_dates() function below.

```
function weeks_between_dates($d1,$d2)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($d1);
    $t2 = strtotime($d2);
    $out = array();
    while ($now <= $t2) {
        $out[] = date('W', $t1);
        $t1 = strtotime('+1 week', $t1);
    }
    return $out;
}

print_r( weeks_between_dates('2015-01-01','2015-12-31') ); // 01..53
print_r( weeks_between_dates('2016-01-01','2016-12-31') ); // 01..52
```