# how to find number of weeks with start and end date between two days using php

Tags: php

1. How to find number of weeks with start and end date between two dates in PHP?
   for example:

> 2015-04-01 
>   2015-04-30

Comment: What is your expected result? In other words, you want include partial weeks? (Apr 1st = friday, Apr 30 = saturday). Also, weeks start on sunday or monday?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Week Numbers between two dates in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037355/get-week-numbers-between-two-dates-in-php)

Comment: I want weeks start on monday to friday

Answer (score 1):

```
function count_weeks_and_days($from, $to) {
    $day   = 24 * 3600;
    $from  = strtotime($from);
    $to    = strtotime($to) + $day;
    $diff  = abs($to - $from);
    $weeks = floor($diff / $day / 7);
    $days  = $diff / $day - $weeks * 7;
    $out   = array();
    if ($weeks) $out[] = "$weeks Week" . ($weeks > 1 ? 's' : '');
    if ($days)  $out[] = "$days Day" . ($days > 1 ? 's' : '');
    return implode(', ', $out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dates to unix times and then count the number of weeks.

```
<?php
$date1=strtotime($date1);
$date2=strtotime($date2);
$weeks=( $date2>$date1? $date2-$date1 : $date1-$date2)/(60*60*24*7);
echo "Number of weeks : ".floor($weeks);
?>
```